# move_upload_files and permissions

Tags: php, permissions, move, user-management

I have a user "broker" with home directory, when I tried to transfer files over SFTP, the files got moved from local to server, but using the function move_upload_files function, it gives **"failed to open stream: Permission denied".**

```
chown -R broker:www-data /home/broker/www/

find /home/broker/www/ -type d -exec chmod 750 {} ";"
find /home/broker/www/ -type f -exec chmod 640 {} ";"

# groups www-data
www-data : www-data broker ispapps ispconfig
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Webserver is running as www-data?

Comment: Yes, I think it's better to run it as a user "broker": `broker:broker`